# Confused on how to implement this finite state machine

Tags: java

Suppose I have a String that consists of a sequence of characters from a set
{'D','P','S','W'}
Each character would represent a word
"dry","paint","sand" and "wipe

Implement by finite state machine is confusing me, here is a diagram

[image]

I can post my code as well

public class State {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "";
    int currentState = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i += 1) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);

        switch (currentState) {
        case 0:

            if (c == 'P') {
                currentState = 2;
            } else if (c == 'S') {
                currentState = 1;
            } else {
                System.out.println("false");

            }
            break;
        case 1:
            if (c == 'W') {
                currentState = 3;
            } else {
                System.out.println("false");
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if (c == 'D') {
                currentState = 0;
            } else if (c == 'S') {
                currentState = 1;
            }
            System.out.println("false");
        }
        break;
        case 3:
            if(c == 'P') {
                currentState = 2;
            } else if(c == 'S') {
                currentState = 1;
            }
            System.out.println("False");

    }
    System.out.println(currentState == 3);
}
```

Comment: post your relevant code

Comment: http://pastebin.com/1sDHY3Cz

Comment: Thanks, but please post your code directly into the question using the edit function. Also, what is the problem with the code?

Comment: Is it safe to assume that all missing links are self-referential? For every possible character there must be a link - either to a reject state, to itself or another state.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have it implemented in a graphical format.

Look up the various means by which you can covert (or document) this in a tabular format.  When you have the transition tables, it then becomes a matter of encoding those into the programming language where your program holds the current state, accepts the input, and then transitions the state according to the transition table.

Example of state tables can be found at wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_transition_table

Map the transitions in your diagram to the table, and then write a routine which sets the initial state into a variable, then asks for an input, and transitions according to the value encoded in the table.  The easiest way to do the transition part is to encode the table into the program itself, using a data structure.

The purposefully incomplete code below should give you a jump-start.

```
public class StateInput {

    private int state;

    private char input;

    public StateInput(int state, char input) {
        this.state = state;
        this.input = input;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        hash = 83 * hash + this.state;
        hash = 83 * hash + this.input;
        return hash;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (object instanceof StateInput) {
            StateInput other = (StateInput)object;
            return state == other.state && input == other.input;
        }
        return false;
    }

}


public class Machine {

    private Map<StateInput, Integer> transitionTable;

    private final int initialState;

    private int currentState;

    private Set<Integer> acceptanceStates;

    public Machine() {
        ... code goes here ...
        currentState = initialState;
    }

    public void readInput(char input) {
        Integer newState = transitionTable.get(StateInput(curentState, input));
        if (newState == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("no transition for input");
        } else {
            currentState = newState;
        }
    }

    public boolean isAcceptable() {
        return acceptanceStates.contains(currentState);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

well, your doubt is a bit confused, but you start in state 0, is your initial state, so, if you read or detect a 'P' you going to the state 2, from there, you need to check what comes, according to your diagram if  you read a 'D' you return to state 0 :), the same for the others letters and states

I see your code, your must start in the state 0

// start in state 0
  int currentState = 0;

and your case 0 must be the case 2, and your case 1 must be the case 0 :)

Answer (score 0):

You need a state variable that tells you which state you are in. You need a transition function that takes this state variable and an input. The input in your case would be one word of your sequence.

The transition function then changes the state variable accordingly.
You could start with a switch on the state variable and then call subfunctions that evaluate the input based on the current state. That way your transition function does not get overly big.

Finally, you need a function that splits the whole program input (cf. String.split) into inputs for your transition function.
Initiate your state variable with the initial state. For each part of your input (commonly called token), call the transition function. Output the state variable.

I won't give you code. This looks too much like homework ;)

Comment: Thank you, i'll update the code. well, it isn't homework. We have do to a few questions weekly(not handed in) and will have a quiz every week with a similar question from the list.

Comment: OK. Your transition function has to update the state variable even if there is no arrow (transition) in the automaton. In that case use a special value (0 or -1 or whatever) to mark it invalid. Your automaton should never leave the invalid state.

Comment: is it any better? or should case 0 return false?

Comment: No. It's just an arbitrary constant. Currently you are outputting false but you not stop! You could potentially output 500x false and then true. What kind of result would that be?